# How are vcpus distributed in AIX LPARs?

Tags: virtual-machine, cpu, aix

I'm reading some docs about LPAR on AIX/IBM server
I have this schema:

```
+---------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|LPARS          |Virtual cpus    | processing units                                      |
+---------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|               |Min | Desired   | Max| Min | Desired    | Max | Cap/Uncap | Weigh| Pool |
+---------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|LPAR1          |1   | 4         |  4 | 0.1 | 1          | 4   |  Uncap    | 64   | 8    |
|LPAR2          |1   | 4         |  4 | 0.1 | 1          | 4   |  Uncap    | 64   | 8    |
|LPAR3          |1   | 4         |  4 | 0.1 | 1          | 4   |  Uncap    | 128  | 8    |
|LPAR4          |1   | 4         |  4 | 0.1 | 1          | 4   |  Uncap    | 128  | 8    |
+---------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

As I understand, all vpars has one vcpu at boot (min), the desired cpu is 4 and max is 4, but if we have max 8 (pool) vcpus, how is  4 vcpus per vpar possible? As I know 4*4=16 not 8.
Can someone explain better how the vcpu distribution works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick answer is that each virtual CPU doesn't require a full physical CPU (processing unit) -- only a fraction of one, from 0.1 (earlier models) to 0.05 (Power7+). The OS on each of your LPARs will see 4 CPUs and each of those CPUs will be guaranteed time slices equivalent to 1/4 of a physical CPU (1 desired processing unit divided by 4 desired virtual CPUs). Because the LPARs are uncapped, their virtual CPUs can receive more physical CPU time slices than their desired processing units indicates. If there is competition for those physical CPU cycles, then the time is portioned out based on the LPAR weight.

The Min and Max values come into play during DLPAR operations -- they simply define the upper and lower limits when you attempt to dynamically change the desired value. The system will prevent you from setting the desired processing units beyond what the system has available.

There's more information in the [IBM PowerVM Virtualization Introduction and Configuration](https://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redbooks/pdfs/sg247940.pdf) Redbook and
the [IBM POWER Virtualization Best Practices Guide](https://www.ibm.com/downloads/cas/JVGZA8RW).

Answer (score 2):

As you can see in your table the minimum vCPU is 1. Which mean in moment 0 you will use 4 vCPUs. The you may have up to 4 per LPAR, but not on the same time. Also you have weight which will play role when redistribute available vCPUs between LPARs